# How to download csv file using postman from SSO protected end point?

Tags: single-sign-on, postman, postman-pre-request-script

Hey guys is there any way to fetch a file using POSTMAN from external cloud environment which is SSO(Single Sign-On) protected.

because when I hit the URL in the browser it asks me to log in, then I can access that API to download the file but the concern is the endpoint is associated with POST method, which we can't access from the browser address bar.